# ADOQuery Master/Detail

Tags: delphi

How can I setup a ADOQuery to filter the data to display all lakes that have Brook trout in a DBGrid?

**Data:**

Nate Pond - LakeMaps.Lake_Name

```
Brook trout - Species.Species_Name

Creek chub

Golden shiner
```

Black Pond

```
Brook trout

Brown bullhead

Common shiner
```

Lake Placid

```
Lake trout

Smallmouth bass

Yellow perch
```

**MDB Database**

ADoTable1 = LakeMaps **MASTER**

ADOTable2 = Species **DETAIL**

**Relationship**

```
LakeMaps Table
LakeMaps.Field[0] = Lake_ID: Autonumber --- ]
LakeMaps.Field[1] = Lake_Name: Text---      |
                                            |Relationship set in the access database
Species Table                               |
Species.Field[0] = Species_ID: numeric ---  ]    
Species.Field[1] = Species_Name: text
```

The Species Table is a Detail the LakeMaps is the Master

How can I setup a ADOQuery to filter the data to display all lakes that have Brook trout in a DBGrid?

**Filtered Data:**

Nate Pond

```
Brook trout

Creek chub

Golden shiner
```

Black Pond

```
Brook trout

Brown bullhead

Common shiner
```

Comment: Is this a different question than: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/465647/filtering-a-tclientdataset-on-a-nesteddataset-field ??

Answer (score 1):

You can set `Filtered = true` and then use `OnFilterRecord` event and check if detail dataset contains requested value (this can be done in loop or with `Locate` procedure of dataset)

This will probably be very slow on larger amount of data. In those situations I usually filter master records directly in SQL. Something like this:

```
SELECT * FROM LakeMaps 
WHERE Lake_ID in (SELECT Lake_ID 
         FROM Species INNER JOIN SpeciesLakesRelation 
             ON (Species.Species_ID = SpeciesLakesRelation.Species_Id) 
         WHERE SPECIES_NAME = 'Brook Trout')
```

This SQL returns records from Lakes that have 'Brook Trout'.

`SpeciesLakesRelation` is table that contains relation between LakeMaps and Species.

Answer (score 0):

Problem with your query in is that text in query must be in apostrophes. If `ComboBoxSpecies.Text` has value `Brook Trout`, then SQL evaluates to:

```
SELECT * FROM LakeMaps WHERE Lake_ID in 
  (SELECT Lake_ID FROM Species INNER JOIN LakeMaps ON 
     (Species.Species_ID = LakeMaps.Lake_Id) 
   WHERE SPECIES_NAME = Brook Trout)
```

Note that Brook Trout is not in apostrophes, so you get syntax error from MsAccess.

**Edit:**
As Gerry noted in comment:

- apostrophes should be added using `QuotedStr` function, instead of double apostrophe.
- best solution is to use query parameter

Delphi code, using `QuotedStr`, should look like this:

```
ADOQuery1.SQL.Add( 'SELECT * FROM LakeMaps WHERE Lake_ID in ' +
  '(SELECT Lake_ID FROM Species INNER JOIN LakeMaps ON ' +
  '(Species.Species_ID = LakeMaps.Lake_Id) ' +
  'WHERE SPECIES_NAME = ' + QuotedStr(ComboBoxSpecies.Text) + ')');
```

Now, if `ComboBoxSpecies.Text`   has value `Brook Trout`, then this string:

```
'WHERE SPECIES_NAME = ' + QuotedStr(ComboBoxSpecies.Text) + ')'
```

evaluates as:

```
WHERE SPECIES_NAME = 'Brook Trout')
```

Comment: Thanks Zendar...  have it almost working now.  How do you avoid having to log-in.  I tried to remove 'Admin' from connectionstring but when running always requires login even if all set to active in Delphi IDE?

Comment: You need to do 2 things: set user name and password in connection string and set TAdoConnection property LoginPrompt to false.

Comment: The above sample will fail if you get a value in ComboBoxSpecies.Text which has an apostrophe. Either use QuotedStr as suggested by  Fabricio above, or better use a parameterised query (safer from SQL injection as well - may not be an issue if Combobox style is csDropDownList).